# Travis CI troubleshooting guide

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to get my first Travis CI Build to run with a Python setup but the build get the status of #Errored and the simple Travis interface is leaving me without any help as to why.
I've followed:

[Travis getting started guide](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/)

Validated my .travis.yml:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
  # does not have headers provided, please ask https://launchpad.net/~pypy/+archive/ppa
  # maintainers to fix their pypy-dev package.
  - "pypy"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install .
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I can't find any troubleshoot guide any similar resource to investigate why it doesn't work, how to I get any information about why the build is failing?

[Link to my build](https://travis-ci.org/adrianforsius/personal)

Comment: There should be a display of the build's output in Travis's interface. Since you don't link to your build, none of us can guess whether it's actually giving you one or not.

Comment: I've revised the question including the build, however even tho it is not working where do I find information about failing builds?

Comment: Click on the links to the builds, i.e., https://travis-ci.org/adrianforsius/personal/jobs/34801416 (where it tells you that `pip install .` failed because you didn't provide a setup.py.)

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't realize that the number was clickable!

Answer (score 1):

As far as a trouble shooting guide, the docs are the closest thing: http://docs.travis-ci.com/. The IRC channel is another option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your build jobs details + logs shows that you got invalid requirements for python 3.2 and 3.3.

Notice that for the others stacks (ex pypy) your requirements are ok, and related jobs are green.

Either review your requirements list or remove stack "3.2" and "3.3" if it's not mandatory for your context.